# correct design for pointer members of a c++ class in qt design

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, design-patterns

I want to design and write a class in c++ with qt design pattern. In my original class I just have one data member which is inherited from [QSharedData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qshareddata.html) that is named MyClassData, and some member functions. Now my question is if MyClassData includes Pointer, how should I define this Pointer in that class?

The following codes will clear my question:

```
class MyClassData : public QSharedData {
public:
     MyClassData();
     // one of these pointers is correct ?
     int * myNormalPointer;
     QSharePointer<int> myQSharedPointer;
     QScopedPointer<int> myQScopedPointer;
};
class MyClass {
public:
     MyClass();
     // and some other member functions ...
     QSharedDataPointer<MyClassData> data;
}
```

If my question will not be closed!, I wanna ask that generally is it correct to always avoid from defining Pointers in member field of a class?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the QT docs..

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscopedpointer.html

QSharedPointer is essentially `std::shared_ptr`, QScopedPointer is essentially `std::unique_ptr`, which were added in C++11.

All of these "smart pointers" behave differently and should be used in different contexts, but they're all for `delete`ing dynamically allocated memory on the heap when it shouldn't be used anymore, how this is accomplished depends on the type of smart pointer used.

If the pointer should be for reference only (ie the object doesn't "own" the memory (doesn't have the responsibility to `delete` it)), just use `int*`. If it's dynamically allocated, look into these smart pointers, whether it be `QSharedPointer` and `QScopedPointer` or `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`.

TL;DR, look into how `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` are used, they're very similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you're about to keep Qt design style of your class you have to choose between `QSharedPointer<int> myQSharedPointer` and `QScopedPointer<int> myQScopedPointer`. Difference is that `QSharedPointer<int>` is more complex than `QScopedPointer<int>` providing threadsafety and more debugging info. `QScopedPointer<int>` is for simple tasks.

Comment: This completely discounts the big differences between `QScopedPointer` and `QSharedPointer` which should dictate which one to use.